# How to have a VIP for 2 servers ( Prod and Dr )

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, ip

We have prod and dr servers, we would like to have VIP for them.  They are not exposed to internet. Any one server will be active for 1st 6 months, and after DR drill DR will be turned as prod and DR will act as prod for next 6 months. Here, we have upstream systems which pushes files ( csv or text or zip ) via SFTP to our servers which would be nearly 200 - 300mb size per day. Currently, during every DR drill these upstream systems need to raise change request to update the ip before DR drill. So we have decided to have an VIP from our side. So that they can use VIP to transfer files via SFTP. 
Note: DR server will be up and won't be active.

Note : File transfer is not recommended for SFTP. 
What are the possibilities to have a VIP.

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

1) It may be better to use DNS  records for this, rather than a virtual IP. This can often be simpler to manage, and have less room for failure. So, you might have: `prod.internal.example.com` points to `serverA.internal.example.com` and `dr.internal.example.com` points to `serverB.internal.example.com`. Later, when you change the roles, you can just change where the host names point to.

2) SFTP will verify the host key. If you change the host behind the IP or hostname you connect to, many clients will complain that the host key has changed. You will need to take this into account.

Comment: from your point of view, every time i go on DR drill. I need to keep updating the names to counter party.( upstream app). Upstream should have only on name with them.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understood your reply. However, the above mentioned configuration can be used very successfully.

If you need to track the real server, as well as the role of the server, then you can have a more complicated dns setup.

serverA.int.example.com A 192.168.1.10
serverB.... A 192.168.1.20
prod CNAME serverA
dr CNAME serverB

And during a failover drill, you can change the prod and dr cnames.